# BeautifulSoup - find the element following an already found element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to find the **ul** element under the **h2** element.

[image]

I find the **h2** element with:

```
tmpSpan = soupDetail.find_all("a", {"class": "external"})
tmpParent = tmpSpan.parent
```

I have tried several methods to get the following **ul** element (descendants, next_sibling, next-element, etc. ) but the result is always the **span** element in the **h1**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> tmpSpan = soupDetail.find_all("a", {"class": "external"})
> tmpParent = tmpSpan.parent
> ```

Above code from your question will lead to an `AttributeError`, cause ResultSet object has no attribute `parent`.

---

Select your tags more specific for example with `css selectors` - An build it based on tag or id, cause they are mor static then classes.

Get the `<h2>` based on its content:

```
soup.select_one('h2:has(span#External_links)')
```

Get the next sibling `<ul>` of such these `<h2>`:

```
soup.select_one('h2:has(span#External_links) + ul')
```

or

```
soup.select_one('h2:has(span#External_links)').find_next('ul')
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<h2>
    <span id="External_links"></span>
    <span>
        <a class="external"></a>
    </span>
</h2>
<ul></ul>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('h2:has(span#External_links) + ul'))

##output
<ul></ul>
```